# Pyspark Melting Null Columns

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
# +----+------------+----------+-----------+
# | id |  c_type_1  | c_type_2 |  c_type_3 |
# +----+------------+----------+-----------+
# |  1 |    null    |   null   |     r     |
# |  2 |     a      |   null   |    null   |
# |  3 |    null    |   null   |    null   |
# +---+-------------+----------+-----------+
```

I need to convert it into something like this:

```
# +----+------------+------------+
# | id |   c_type   | c_type_val |
# +----+------------+------------+
# |  1 |  c_type_3  |     r      |
# |  2 |  c_type_1  |     a      |
# |  3 |    null    |    null    |
# +---+-------------+------------+
```

Each row only has either one c_type value or all c_type values will be null.

I'm currently melting the rows like so:

```python
def melt(df, id_cols, value_cols, c_type, c_value):
    v_arr = []
    for c in value_cols:
        v_arr.append(struct(lit(c).alias(c_type), col(c).alias(c_value)))

    vars_and_vals = array(*v_arr)

    tmp = df.withColumn("vars_and_vals", explode(vars_and_vals))

    cols = id_cols + [
        col("vars_and_vals")[x].alias(x) for x in [c_type, c_value]]
    return tmp.select(*cols)


melted = melt(df, df.columns[:1], df.columns[1:4], 'c_type', 'c_type_val')

melted.filter(melted.c_type_val.isNotNull()).show()
```

The problem is that filtering the null values for c_type_val filters out the row for id == 3 (any rows with null c_type). I need a way to melt and filter to retain the third row as null c_type and value.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `pandas`,  It may give you a idea to solve this,

```
temp=df.filter(like='c_type')
df= pd.merge(df,temp[temp.notnull()].stack().reset_index(), left_index=True, right_on=['level_0'],how='left')
df=df[['id','level_1',0]].reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={'level_1':'c_type',0:'c_type_val'})
print df
```

Output:

```
   id    c_type c_type_val
0   1  c_type_3          r
1   2  c_type_1          a
2   3       NaN        NaN
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I can't use pandas in this environment since it will run in AWS Glue that doesn't support additional libraries yet.